# Mongoose instance method `this` does not refer to model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**EDIT:** I have discovered that `console.log(this)` ran inside the `setPassword` method returns only the hash and salt. I'm not sure why this is happening, however it indicates that `this` is not refering to the model as it should.

---

I have the following schema with the following instance method:

```
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: String, required: true},
  email: {type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true}},
  joinDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  clips: [clipSchema],
  hash: {type: String},
  salt: {type: String}
})

userSchema.methods.setPassword = (password) => {
  this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex')
  this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 100000, 512, 'sha512').toString('hex')
}
```

The instance method is called here, then the user is saved:

```
let user = new User()

user.username = req.body.username
user.email = req.body.email
user.setPassword(req.body.password)

user.save((err) => {
  if (err) {
    sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err)
  } else {
    let token = user.generateJwt()
    sendJsonResponse(res, 200, { 'token': token })
  }
})
```

However, when I view the `users` collection in the mongo CLI, there is no mention of `hash` or `salt`.

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("576338b363bb7df7024c044b"),
 "email" : "boss@potato.com",
 "username" : "Bob",
 "clips" : [ ],
 "joinDate" : ISODate("2016-06-16T23:39:31.825Z"),
 "__v" : 0 
}
```

Comment: Try using `userSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password) {...}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason it was not working was because I was using an arrow method. I had to make it a normal function:

`userSchema.methods.setPassword = function (password) {`

The reason is because arrow functions treat `this` differently from regular functions. Please see the following for more detail:

http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

Comment: That is actually pointed out in the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods

Comment: How to set this method generic across all schema. I want to make this method globally available to all schema then?