# "this" is not refering the the user object in mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have the following code to save user object to database from express,

```
api.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
    var user = new User();
    user.name = req.body.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.setPassword(req.body.password);
    user.save(function (err) {
        err ? res.send(err) : res.json({ message: 'User Created!'})
    })
})
```

and below here for the user schema,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: String,
})

userSchema.methods.setPassword = function (password) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            this.password = hash; // <= `this` will not be saved to mongoDB
        })
    })
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

When it performed the `save` function, it will show that the `password` was `undefined` and will save the object to mongodb without `password` value.

I've checked the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871165/mongoose-instance-method-this-does-not-refer-to-model) as well and changed all my functions to not using arrow method but it still got the same error.

The same issue when i was using middleware hook that `this` reference was not referring to user object. Below here for my another approach,

```
userSchema.pre('save', (next) => {

    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function (err, salt) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            this.password = hash; // <= `this` will not be saved to mongoDB
            next();
        })
    })
})
```

Any idea for this value to be saved to database when perform `save`?

Comment: You can still use the old es5 way of storing `this` to a variable at the start of the function. `var self = this;` and `self.password = hash;` inside of other functions.

Comment: @TalhaAwan yes, I did that as well, but `self` value was `undefined` as well. It seems that `this` was not referring to the `user` model here.

Comment: Did you `console.log(this)` to check what it actually is? I think in this case it is a local variable of the anonymous function of the bcrypt.hash callback.

Comment: @MaKobi I didn't do `console.log` inside its method but I try to see the `password` value instead after I've called the `setPassword` method inside the `api.post` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code, Hope it will work for you:

```
userSchema.methods.setPassword = function (password) {
    var pswd=password;
    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        bcrypt.hash(pswd, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            pswd = hash;
            console.log(pwsd); // your decripted password
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: the `pswd` won't be passed out of the function since the way that I want is to pass the `hash` value to the `password` property of the `user` model. The properties that being used is inside `userSchema`.

Answer (score 0):

I will elaborate more in the next days (I want to test a couple of things) but the error, I think, is because the meaning of `this` in JS is tricky.

Basically `this` is not a reference to the function's lexical scope, it is binding done in the context where the function is called.

So, as a fast solution while I elaborate more, I would recommend you to encrypt the password in:
`user.setPassword(encrypt(req.body.password));` and simplify the `mongoose's setPassword function`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `this` to refer to the userSchema context, you can use arrow functions for the bcrypt callbacks. Arrow functions will not create a new function scope, so it will preserve the original context.

```
userSchema.methods.setPassword = function (password) { 
  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, (err, salt) => { 
    if (err) return console.log(err);    
    bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (err, hash) => { 
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      this.password = hash; // <= `this` will be the user object
    })
  })
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions